# Encrypt excel workbook with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to find a straightforward solution. How can I create a macro to encrypt the current active workbook with a password and another separate macro that will remove the password?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Password = "Password" will set one. How can I remove it now?

Comment: If I just leave .Password="". It removes it

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself but it seemed easy enough to google: https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-password-protect-excel-file/

What follows are simple copy-pasted excerpts from the linked page.

encrypt:

```vb
'Save file with password required to open
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Password:="fileOpenPassword"

'Save file to allow access, but requires password to modify
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs  writeResPassword:="modifyFilePassword"

'Save file with password required to open and modify the file
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs  Password:="fileOpenPassword", _
writeResPassword:="modifyFilePassword"
```

decrypt:

```vb
'Open password protected file
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\marks\Documents\PasswordProtectedFile.xlsm", _
Password:="fileOpenPassword", writeResPassword:="fileModifyPassword"
```

Refer to the linked page for more information regarding catching errors etc.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking to decrypt it though. I would like to remove it altogether

Comment: @pandasnew123455 Excel can't open the file if it's encrypted, you need the password to decrypt it to open it in the first place. *Then* you save a copy of it (`SaveAs`) again without a password, and that copy has the password removed. Or are you looking for workbook/worksheet *protection*, which is something entirely different?